# Plotting partial sums and its Cesàro means

Tags: plotting

I have the function as shown in the first line of the code and its partial sum in the second line of the code below.

```
f[x_] := Abs[x];
s[k_, x_] := (Pi/2) + Sum[((-1)^(n) - 1) 2/(Pi n^(2)) Cos[n x], {n, 1, k}]
```

Then I have the [Cesàro means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) of the function:

$$F_{n}(f)=\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{m=0} S_{m}(f)$$

Originally I plot just the function and its partial sum with the code

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums}], {x, -0.5, 0.5}
```

Now if I want to add in the 4th term of the Cesàro means, may I know how can I do so? I made a few changes and there is always a `+` symbol appearing inline which I believe is due to some mistake in my program

The original plot without the Cesàro means is

```
f[x_] := Abs[x];
s[k_, x_] := Pi/2 + Sum[((-1)^(n) - 1) 2/(Pi n^(2)) Cos[n x], {n, 1, k}] 
partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 4}];
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums}], {x, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

When I introduce the `Piecewise` function to add the Cesàro means to my graph, no drawings were generated. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to straighten out some of the notation. Whereas your partial sum function `s` depends only upon the index `k` and the variable `x` but not the function `f`, your list `partialsums` does not depend on `x` and your Cesaro partial-sum function, as you expressed it in $\text{LaTeX}$ form, includes an explicit dependence on `f`. Let's omit the `f` on the last and do include the `x` with `partialsums`. Then:

```
f[x_] := Abs[x]
s[k_, x_] := 
    Pi/2 + Sum[((-1)^(n) - 1) 2/(Pi n^(2)) Cos[n x], {n, 1, k}]
partialsums[x_] = Table[s[n, x], {n, 4}];

c[n_, x_] := (1/n) Sum[s[m, x], {m, 0, n - 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums[x], c[4, x]}], {x, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: you didn't define the cesaro means in the code. So Mathematica can't generate a graph for it.

Comment: @Sandra: I fixed that omission. BTW, did you know you can directly embed LaTeX code in questions here, by enclosing within dollar signs?

Comment: Thanks Murray. Oh I didn't know about that. In my post, I think VLC edit it for me. Now when I graph your code, I do receive the function line and the 4th term of the partial sum line but for the 4th term of the Cesaro means there are two lines generated. Can you have a check on what is wrong in the code?

Comment: When I put in the legends, it seem not match up: PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=x", "Fourier, 4 terms", "Cesaro, 4 terms"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed, Red}]

Comment: @sandra Since Murray is using partialsums in the plot which is a list with 4 functions you get 6 plots in total. You don't see all of them because there are two twin function involved. The printed functions you get in the output are caused by a missing ; in the code, or a definition using = instead of a :=.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Oh yes, there is a missing ; in the code at partial sums. Now I get what you mean. Do you think it is possible to group the two lines that is produce by partial sums under one color? And the other one which is the cesaro means under another color so that readers won't confused it? I can't seem to get the partialsums' two lines to have the same color.

Comment: @murray, if I modified your code for partialsums and the cesaro means for the 4 to be {4}, I do get the intended graph. But I would like to confirm, since I put a bracket around the letter 4 i.e.{4} does that mean those repetitions is not showing up? Just to confirm in case I did wrong as I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: @Sandra: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking about the `4` and `{4}`. If you refer to the right-hand side of the definition of `partialsums`, then the 2nd argument `{n,4}` is an abbreviated form of the "iterator" `{n,1,4}`. So you get the first 4 partial sums.

Comment: @Sandra: If you *also* want all 4 of the first 4 Cesaro sums, not just the 4th (which is what your Q asked!), then yes, define, say, `cesaroSums[x_] := Table[c[n, x], {n, 4}]`.

Comment: @murray: You are right! I am asking about the definition of partialsums. As for the second argument which you mention {n,4} means {n,1,4}. Now if I put {n,{4}}, does that mean it is of the form {n,4} only without the 1 in between n and 4?

Comment: @Sandra: You can do some simple experiments to discover how such iterators work. Look, e.g., at evaluating the results of `Table[x^n, {n,4}]`, on the one hand, and `Table[x^n, {n, {4}}]`, on the other hand. Then read the entry for `Table` in the Mathematica Documentation Center.

Comment: @murray: For my graph, drawing it out with and without brackets didn't show anything because the graphs are repeating and so you won't notice the difference. I had also look through the Wolfram documentation before I post to you but it would seem there is not much information but never mind. Thanks!